# How can I show passwords that are being typed in?

Tags: linux, passwords, redhat

I know it's a huge security risk and I'd never use it, but I'm showing a product that is about password management, so I want a password to be shown on the command line as I'm typing it in. Is there any way to do this in redhat linux?

Comment: Just read it the same way as the username.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Long answer: yes, but then you would have to change the source code of the `shadow-utils` program and recompile it for your demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
/bin/bash
read -p "password: " PASS
echo $PASS | sudo -S $1
```

and run as `script.sh <command>`